# Require authentication to use the internet

Tags: networking

In my college's computer lab, I want to configure the computers in such a way that whenever a user tries to use the Internet in that lab they are asked to authenticate (provide a username / password) themselves through my computer. Only then they are allowed to use the internet.

I want to implement this using networking techniques and concepts of some kind -- what would be appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

Setup a proxy server like squid.  Require authentication.  Configure the browser on all the computers to use your proxy server.  If possible use a firewall to block all http connections that do not go through your cache.

[Here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication) is a section from the squid faq that describes how to use authentication.

Comment: +1 for squid, first thing I thought of too.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are talking about here is an authenticating proxy server? Microsoft's offering is the [ISA Server](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/default.aspx), but there are also plenty of free ones out there.

Answer (score 1):

Given how you asked the question, I suspect that this approach is beyond your authority and access to implement, but I believe one of the most standard, secure, and compatible methods to do this is through [802.1X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.1X), the IEEE standard "port network access control" protocol.

Be warned that it involves implementing many nontrivial services, like a proper [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) and [RADIUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) setup, so it is not an easy road.

However, it will be more secure and much more reliable than a simple HTTP proxy / captive gateway system.